# catch syscall but exclude syscalls from libc

Tags: gdb

I need to catch mprotect syscalls that is not originating from libc, how can I do that?

I'm not sure if gdb can filter the library names:

```
Catchpoint 2 (call to syscall mprotect), 0x00007ffff74cde57 in mprotect () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to catch mprotect syscalls that is not originating from libc

You could likely achieve *almost* the desired result by filtering out `mprotect` calls originating from the particular address in `libc.so.6` -- *most* calls should be coming from that address:

```
(gdb) cond 2 $rip != 0x00007ffff74cde57
```

If that's not good enough, you should be able to use embedded Python to evaluate arbitrary conditions once catchpoint is reached, using the [Breakpoint.stop](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Breakpoints-In-Python.html) function.